# Error 703... unable to play .mp3 file

Tags: app-inventor

I am building an app using App Inventor in which I need to play some sounds on button click. When I click button once it gives me

> error 703: unable to play file

But on the next time, the sound is played.
Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done it. I just initialized sound component with every file at screen initialize. Now its working fine.

Comment: exactly. [This workaround you also can find in the App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/programming-with-app-inventor/Vk0QQhTPyxo/8cd6DEW2QC8J)

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code,it works fine for me.

```
Uri b = Uri.parse(uri);
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context,b);             
mp.start();
```

Comment: I am using App Inventor, not eclipse. It's a block editor.